# "...if you [sing.] did" — should it not be "do?"

Tags: verb-forms, subjunctives, do-support

I came across the following conversation:

> **A:** I'll let you know where I am planning to go on vacation.
>
> **B:** It wouldn't be vacation if you did.

I am a little confused about the use of *did* here. Shouldn't it be *do* instead?

Answer (score 1):

I would see him if I went.

It would be a vacation if you went.

In this  **type of conditional sentence**, the main clause is would + the verb, and the **IF clause is in the simple past**. Should is also often used  here.

**It wouldn't be vacation if you did.**

**Did** here here is a substitute for not repeating a verb that was mentioned earlier in a conversation.

For example: 
John: **"I want to work during my vacation"**.

Mary: It wouldn't be a vacation if you did. [did substitutes for worked].
It **wouldn't be** a vacation if you **worked**.

In English, **we often use an auxilary to avoid repeating the main  verb again**.

Another example:

John: They **see the car** in the street every night.
Mary: If they **do [see the car]**, they should call the cops.

[Please note, I am only giving simple examples here to make my point.]

Answer (score 0):

It s a question of  [tense agreement](http://www.grammarbank.com/tense-agreement.html):

> It is not a vacation if you do
>
> It wouldn't be a vacation if you did

Comment: Potentially also, "It won't be a vacation if you do"

Answer (score 0):

In your example, "did" is not in the past indicative like "I did it yesterday"; it's in the past subjunctive like "It wouldn't be a vacation if you did."